# Add webserver to existing python service

Tags: python, webserver

I have a script that continually runs, processing data that it gets from an external device. The core logic follows something like:

```py
from external_module import process_data, get_data, load_interesting_things

class MyService:

    def __init__(self):
        self.interesting_items = load_interesting_things()
        self.run()

    def run(self):
        try:
            while True:
                data = get_data()
                for item in self.interesting_items:
                    item.add_datapoint(process_data(data, item))
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass
```

I would like to add the ability to request information for the various interesting things via a RESTful API.

Is there a way in which I can add something like a Flask web service to the program such that the web service can get a stat from the `interesting_items` list to return? For example something along the lines of:

```py
@app.route("/item/<idx>/average")
def average(idx: int):
    avg = interesting_items[idx].getAverage()
    return jsonify({"average":avg})
```

Assuming there is the necessary idx bounds checking and any appropriate locking implemented.

It does not have to be Flask, but it should be light weight. I want to avoid using a database. I would prefer to use a webservice, but if it is not possible without completely restructuring the code base I can use a socket instead, but this is less preferable.

The server would be running on a local network only and usually only handling a single user, sometimes it may have a few.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to move the `run()` method out of the `__init__()` method, so that I could have a global reference to the service, and start the run method in a separate thread. Something along the lines of:

```py
service = MyService()
service_thread = threading.Thread(target=service.run, daemon=True)
service_thread.start()

app = flask.Flask("appname")
...
@app.route("/item/<idx>/average")
def average(idx: int):
    avg = service.interesting_items[idx].getAverage()
    return jsonify({"average":avg})
...
app.run()
```